# Configure spring security with oauth2/openid for session id but also access token

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0

it is possible to configure spring with oauth2 to accept multiple login possibilities?

Currently I have it working with:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception { // @formatter:off
        http.authorizeRequests(authorizeRequests -> authorizeRequests
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated())
                .oauth2Login(AbstractAuthenticationFilterConfigurer::permitAll)
                .addFilterAfter(new CustomAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .logout(logout -> logout.logoutSuccessHandler(oidcLogoutSuccessHandler()))
                .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();
    }  // @formatter:on
```

If one tries to access an authorize ressource, he gets redirected to a login page of an identity provider, logs in and then get a session id on the client side. The access token and the refreh token are held into memory on the server side.

But now I also want to use an access token to access ressources.

But when I do this, the security application context is just null.

What do I have to do?

I have searching in the doc but could not understand how to achieve this.

I would expect to just add in application.properties:
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwk-set-uri

And to add:
.oauth2ResourceServer().jwt() to my HttpSecurity but this does not do the work.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, if Bearer is not set as prefix in the Authorization header when sending the token, then it will not be recognized.
Kind of normal since it is the standard...